# Distance between arbitrary pointers

Tags: c, memory

I am trying to print the distance between two pointers, but I have found that sometimes the code doesn't work well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/**
 * Print the distance between 2 pointers
 */
void distance(int * a0, int * a1){
    size_t difference = (size_t) a1 - (size_t) a0;
    printf("distance between %p & %p: %u\n" ,a0, a1, abs((int) difference));
}
```

Trying this works perfectly!!

```
int main(void){
    int x = 100;
    int y = 3000;
    distance(&x, &y);
    return 0;
}
```

printing (example):

```
distance between 0028ff18 & 0028ff14: 4
```

But start to going wrong with this code

```
int main(void){
    int x = 100;
    int p = 1500;
    int y = 3000;
    distance(&x, &y);
    p = p + 2; // remove unused warning
    // &p
    return 0;
}
```

printing (example):

```
distance between 0028ff18 & 0028ff14: 4
```

When it has to print `8` because of an integer separating this values!

But if I uncomment `//&p`, it works again.

It is as if the variable `p` does not exist until its memory address is used.

I'm using gcc 4.9.3 on windows 7 (64 bits)

Comment: GCC is optimizing it away. Try with `-O0`, though it may still leave some optimizations in. Also, you can use [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t) instead of the `size_t` casts. But note that strictly speaking, only pointers to elements in the same array may meaningfully be subtracted from eachother.

Comment: Like you already noticed, the compiler is optimizing out your variable p because even though you assign to it you never use it, leaving x and y.

Comment: You are better off using an array for this kind of experimentation. You cannot rely on where the linker places a bunch of different variables that may not have anything to do with each other.

Comment: You seem to be on the path to *programming by experimentation*, which will likely teach you tons of misconceptions about C and C compilers. Don't do that. Read the ISO C Standard and recognize that all what you are doing here is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Even if `p` *isn't* optimized out, I don't see why the compiler couldn't just keep `p` it in a register since its address is never taken... when the address *is* taken, suddenly there's a need for it to actually have a memory address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is valid only between pointers to elements of the same array, or one past the end. Going against that will have unpredictable and implementation-defined results. In this case, it seems you have found the answer yourself: gcc is optimizing `p` away, but in any case, you can't assume any specific order of variables in memory, yet alone do pointer arithmetic.

Also, this:

```
size_t difference = (size_t) a1 - (size_t) a0;
```

Should be:

```
ptrdiff_t difference = a1 - a0;
```

The correct type for the difference between two pointers is `ptrdiff_t` (defined in `stddef.h`). You shouldn't cast the pointers to `size_t` because pointer values are not necessarily representable in a `size_t` (if you want a numeric type to convert pointers to, use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`).

The `%p` format specifier expects a `void *`, so you should cast the pointers, and the correct format specifier for `ptrdiff_t` is `%td`:

```
printf("distance between %p & %p: %td\n", (void *) a0, (void *) a1, difference);
```

Comment: I'm under the impression that a pointer of any type can be passed to a function expecting void; no need for a cast. Am I out of date? (Sometimes I remember things from earlier C standards, not realizing they've changed since.)

Comment: @ArlieStephens That is generally true (when the function prototype explicitly expects a `void *` pointer type), but in the case of `printf(3)`, the pointers are being passed as part of the variable arguments list, so there is no automatic conversion to `void *`. Because the representation of a pointer may be different when converted to `void *`, and the `%p` format specifier expects a `void *`, we need to cast it.

Answer (score 4):

`p` is not used in your program and is likely to be optimized out. Anyway this is implementation details and the compiler is free to even change the order of the `x` and `y` objects in memory.

Answer (score 4):

> it is as if the variable p not exist until its memory address is used

gcc will optimize away any variables that do not affect the behavior of the program.

Secondly, you *cannot* assume that variables are laid out in any particular order in memory, and the "distance" between any two may be completely meaningless.  The only time you can rely on the distance between two pointers to have any meaning is when they are both pointing to elements within the same array object.

Comment: Even worse, subtracting pointers not pointing (in)to the same object (or just past it), is *undefined behavior*.